# php curl how to request hls streaming resources and play with html video tag

Tags: curl, http-live-streaming, fluid, php-curl

for some authorization purposes i want to use custom user agent with curl request so in order to grant access based on custom user agent.

I found this code for HLS streaming urls and i embedded with fluid video tag but its not working. any suggestion?

```
  <video id='hls-video'> <source src='<?php 
 class VideoStream
{

public function callback($curl,$data)
{
    ob_get_clean();
    if (($data === false) || ($data == null))
    {
        throw new Exception (curl_error($curl) . " " . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    $length = strlen($data);
    header("Content-type: application/x-mpegURL");
    header("Transfer-encoding: chunked");
    header("Connection: keep-alive");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
    header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
    echo $data;
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    return $length;
}

public function getStreamChunk($hls_url)
{
    $url = $hls_url;    //url of noted video server
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $url,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'mycustomagent',
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION => array($this, "callback")
        )
    );
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
}


}   getStreamChunk("https://example.com/example/186.m3u8"); ?> ' type='application/x-mpegURL'>
               </video>
```

error says : code 500

Comment: What does the error message tell you about this? Error 500 is pretty generic

Comment: error detail " Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received"

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, keep in mind that PHP is executed on the sever, so only a single chunk would be sent to the browser